# Showing that $A$ is NOT an infinitesimal generator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

As a state space, choose $X=L^{2}(0,1)$.

Let $A$ be defined as $\displaystyle Af=\frac{df}{d\zeta}$ with domain

$D(A)=\{f\in L^{2}(0,1)|f$ is absolutely continuous and $\frac{df}{d\zeta}\in L^{2}(0,1)\}$.

I need to show that $A$ is not an infinitesimal generator on $L^{2}(0,1)$.

I can do this by showing that $\alpha I-A$ is not injective for any $\alpha>0$.

How can I prove that it is not injective?

Comment: Write down what it means that $(\alpha I - A) f = 0$. Then given any $\alpha > 0$, find a solution $0 \ne f \in X$.

Comment: @HansEngler Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming all vector spaces are over $\mathbb{C}$.

To show that $\alpha I - A$ is not injective for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, it is sufficient to find (given $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$) an $f \in L^2(0,1;\mathbb{C})$ such that $\alpha f - Af = 0$.

Set $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$. Then $|f(x)| \le e^{\max(0,\Re \alpha)}$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and hence $f \in L^2$. Also,
$$
A f(x) = f'(x) = \alpha e^{\alpha x} = \alpha f(x)
$$
and therefore   $\alpha f - Af = 0$.

Comment: Note that in this case there is nothing lost by assuming the spaces are over $\mathbb{C}$, because when $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the $f$ presented maps into $\mathbb{R}$. Also +1, good answer. The conclusion here is important for differential equations: it says that $H^1((0,1))$ (which is $D(A)$ here) is too big for the solution to a DE to be unique on it in general. Some initial or boundary conditions are required. (For instance, $A$ is indeed injective if we require homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions and have $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.)